# Drawing a Cone and Cylinder using GLUT

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I've been trying to draw a cone and a cylinder using GLUT. The code I've written so far takes two points from the user, which represents the height of the cone/cylinder, and I want to draw a cone and a cylinder using the two points.

I looked up Google and found standard functions called `glutWireCone()` and `gluCylinder()`, but I'm unable to understand how to use these functions to draw in the manner that I want to draw. Can someone tell me how to draw a cone and a cylinder using the two points? Please let me know if you need some extra information to understand my question correctly.

Here are my `init()` and `main()` functions for you to know the settings of my program:

```
void init(void)
{
   glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   glOrtho(0.0, WINDOW_WIDTH-1, WINDOW_HEIGHT-1, 0, -1000.0, 1000.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  glutInit(&argc, argv);
  glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
  glutInitWindowSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
  glutInitWindowPosition(220, 80);
  glutCreateWindow("Mini Paint - 3D");

  init();

  glutDisplayFunc(display);
  glutMouseFunc(mouseClick);
  glutMotionFunc(mouseMove);
  glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);

  glutMainLoop();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: why would you not want to use OpenGL? It doesn't make any sense for you to use Glut over OpenGL in this case

Comment: @Gmercer015 Okay, then how would you do it in OpenGL?

Comment: i'd suggest to use gluCylinder() as mentioned in the answer provided by @Fructose

Answer (score 2):

Well lets take that `gluCylinder` function and apply it to your display function. Look at it's parameters:

```
void gluCylinder(GLU quadric* quad,
                 GLdouble base,
                 GLdouble top,
                 GLdouble height,
                 GLint    slices,
                 GLint    stacks);
```

So you want to draw a cylinder given the height parameter as input. I'm guessing everything else will remain constant. every time you render you'll want to use `glPushMatrix` and maybe `glRotatef` depending on how you would like its orientation, ending this call with a `glPopMatrix`

Ex: `OnRender(float pHeight)`

```
void OnRender(float pHeight) {
    glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); //clear
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity();

    gluCylinder(quadratic, 0.1f, 0.1f, pHeight, 32, 32);

    glFlush();
}
```

declaring a quadratic object:

```
GLUquadricObj *quadratic;
quadratic = gluNewQuadric();
```

---

gluCylinder documentation: https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluCylinder.xml